# Evaluate $\int\sin^{7}x\cos^4{x}\,dx$

Tags: integration

> $$\int \sin^{7}x\cos^4{x}\,dx$$

\begin{align*}
\int \sin^{7}x\cos^4{x}\,dx&= \int(\sin^{2}x)^3 \cos^4{x}\sin x \,dx\\
&=\int(1-\cos^{2}x)^{3}\cos^4{x}\sin x\,dx,\quad u=\cos x, du=-\sin x\,dx\\
&=-\int(1-u^{2})^3u^4{x}\,du\\
&=-\int (1-3u^2+3u^4-u^6)u^4\,du\\
&=u^4-3u^6+3u^8-u^{10}\\
&=\frac{u^5}{5}-\frac{3u^7}{7}+\frac{3u^9}{9}-\frac{u^{11}}{11}+c
\end{align*}

So we get: $$\frac{\cos^5x}{5}-\frac{3\cos^7x}{7}+\frac{3\cos^{9}x}{9}-\frac{\cos^{11}x}{11}+c$$ Where did I got it wrong?

Comment: If you're just looking for verification of the computation, why not use a CAS like Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: @T.Bongers I have edited the question, I tested it with Wolfram Alpha but did not find the mistake

Comment: Are u interested knowing another way for your integral?

Comment: @BabakS. it is always good to learn new methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it correct?

No, it isn't. You have errors in the following part :

> $$=-\int(1-u^{2})^3u^4{x}du=-\int (1-3u^2+3u^4-u^6)u^4du$$
>   $$=u^4-3u^6+3u^8-u^{10}=\frac{u^5}{5}-\frac{3u^7}{7}+\frac{3u^9}{9}-\frac{u^{11}}{11}+c$$

They should be

$$-\int(1-u^{2})^3u^4du=-\int (1-3u^2+3u^4-u^6)u^4du$$
$$=\int \left(-u^4+3u^6-3u^8+u^{10}\right)du=-\frac{u^5}{5}+\frac{3u^7}{7}-\frac{3u^9}{9}+\frac{u^{11}}{11}+c$$

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is $$\sin x(-\cos^4x-3\cos^6x+3\cos^8x-\cos^{10}x)$$
$$=-\sin x\cos^4x(-1-3\cos^2x+3\cos^4x+\cos^6x)$$

Now,
$$-1-3\cos^2x+3\cos^4x+\cos^6x=-(1-\cos^2x)^3=?$$